# Email body is smaller than emails Signature

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

I have a Gmail account though work. Everytime I email from my gmail account on desktop whenever I see it on my iPhone the body of the email is small.

[image]it’s an iPhone 7. I’m using iOS 14 and the mail app built in.
I have uploaded an image and blacked out the bits where appropriate.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Which iPhone? What version of iOS? How are you accessing mail?  Mail App, GMail App, Outlook App or something else?  What exactly to you mean by "small" (that's a subjective term)?  There's lot of missing details here - please take some time to fill in the missing pieces and remember, we can't see over your shoulder - these things help us help you!

Comment: Hi Allan, I have now made the alterations. Regards

Comment: Does it show like that only on the iPhone or for all recipients?